# What flutter package can be used for this problem?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I've been looking to make an app using Flutter that incorporates a form of image editing. The process would be similar to Instagram stories, allowing users to choose a wide selection of background colours for the story, type some text to put on the background and basic formatting to make the final picture look the way they want (adjust text size, text style, etc.).

More specifically, this is what I want my app to do:

1. Show a selection of backgrounds that the user can choose
2. Allow the user to type some text that would be shown on that background
3. Allow the user to change the formatting and style of the text typed previously

After all of this is done, the app should create a new image that is the compounded image from the text layer and the background layer and produce an image which can be saved in the camera roll/gallery.

*I haven't been able to figure out what package exists that can do this.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found your request, I would like to tell you that it requires a number of steps to complete your requirement. 
And those requirements can be done using some libraries provided by the dart pub as follows.

1. image picker ( https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker )
2. photoeditor ( https://pub.dev/packages/photoeditor#-readme-tab- )
3. image_cropper ( https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper ) 
   etc.

See this youtube tutorial to get the idea: https://youtu.be/hV9gY01m61Y

Hope this will help you. Thanks